# UILabel Doesn't display anything in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any limitation of number of words characters that can be displated on `UILabel`.What i am trying to do is assign almost 10,000+ characters to Label lblUsername which displays the text on label if its less that is almost 1000+ characters, but doesn't display anything when it goes to almost 10,000 characters.Here is my objective-c code

```
 UILabel *lblUsername=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,20)];
        lblUsername.numberOfLines = 0;
       lblUsername.text=@"Username sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfj";
        [lblUsername sizeToFit];
      // lblUsername.tag=i;
       lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        lblUsername.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
       lblUsername.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
```

Comment: Have you added to the view? [self.view addSubview: lblUsername];

Comment: @Greg, I guess he did becaus he says that the UILabel does display the text when it is shorter than 1000 characters.

Comment: who don't you use UITextView instead of UILabel?

Comment: username with 10,000 characters — I wouldn't log in into your service with my iPhone's keyboard…

Comment: What's the frame of the label after `sizeToFit` is called? Could it be because there are some constraints to block your label to get bigger? Could it be because maybe `sizeToFit` stops at device frame?: "In some cases, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method." from the doc of `UIView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your frame is too small to show it (`sizeToFit` additionaly decreases it). This is working sample of your code:

I've just added a property:

```
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *lblUsername;
```

Then I set eveything connected with the view:

```
_lblUsername=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_lblUsername.numberOfLines = 0;
_lblUsername.text=@"Username sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjs sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfj jsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjs sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfj";
// lblUsername.tag=i;
_lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
_lblUsername.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
_lblUsername.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
[self.view addSubview:_lblUsername];
```

Then I set a proper frame (your is too small):

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [_lblUsername setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - 20, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - 20)];
}
```

And everything is working correctly, I can see whole text. There is no limitation on length (but you may need to scroll it later, when text will be too long for your view).

You should do it better than my quick sample here, where i've used `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. You should create separate view, assign it as `self.view`, create that label and other things in your view in the `initWithFrame:` method and layout everything in `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: you should always type views weak properties, as they are owned by the superview

Comment: @vikingosegundo Depends if you're adding them to the superview at all firstly. I've came with this solution as it's faster to explain how frames work, and that was the askers question. My solution will not make any memory leaks nor retain cycles. Ofc in this case it may be weak, but then you'd have to firstly create an ivar and assign it to property after adding to view - i think it's too much explanation for 1 post, especially it isn't the matter here. Also I feel your answer a bit same as my (earlier) one ;P, especially with almost the same code as mine answer...

Comment: I don't say you need to explain everything. but if we provide code, we should do it in a bug-free fashion. you code will result in leaks. for your plagiarism accusation see the comment I left under your answer.

Comment: Calling `sizeToFit` does not make the label smaller. It sizes the label to be big enough for the text. But the call to `sizeToFit` should be after setting the font and everything else.

Comment: My comment was not about plagiarism but posting almost the same answer (what's a sense of it..). About leak I've already told, there is no leak. Keeping 2 strong references won't make a leak. In this case, there is no leak. Your code, as I've pointed in the comment, is not bug-free fashion (nonatomic vs atomic) even more than mine, because your will slower the execution, mine won't.

Comment: @Vive has right. There is no memory leak at all. `addSubView:` retains the subview and releases it on `removeFromSuperview`. This happens implicitly. On dealloc method, deallocated object (before its own destruction) will sent release message to objects stored in instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

In the View Hierarchy Inspector you can see that actually the text is shown but at the beginning of the label is sam extra space.

[image]

---

rmaddy is right in his comment (and I feel stupid not to have seen it earlier): as the font and it's size have a impact on how much size a text needs, you have to call it after setting everything up. so simply do:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *lblUsername=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,20)];
    lblUsername.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblUsername.text=@"Username sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfjUsername sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsfsd  sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdjkskdfksdfkjsdkjfsdjfksjdkskdjfkdsjfkjsdjfkjjdsfkdskjfjskd sd sdfjsjkjksdkfjksdfjksdfjjsdkfjksdfjksdjfkjsdkfjsdjfkjsdkfj";
    // lblUsername.tag=i;
    lblUsername.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    lblUsername.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    lblUsername.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    [lblUsername sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:lblUsername];
}


@end
```

Comment: You should make your label `nonatomic`, as by default it's `atomic`. Having slower `atomic` option isn't required in this case (as in most, especially UI-connected cases). Also why do you call `sizeToFit` in `viewDidLoad`? It's redundant in this code. **I still find your edited answer very(!) similar in code to my (earlier) answer - sad (especially earlier you didn't have the code).**

Comment: My first version already containd the first screenshot. Do you thing I draw it in photoshop? of course I used code in the first place. also layoutSubview is not really a secret method. neither are the CoreGraphics functions. You change the frame entirely, while I only change it in height. There is not much I could have stolen from you.

Comment: I don't claim you've stolen anything. I just claim you've duplicated almost the same answer as mine. I don't have anything against your first screenshot, as it added to the discussion. Latter code is +- a duplication of my answer.

Comment: if you think that the 2 lines and one leak you added to the code in the question are such great and novel work, you may should consider filing a paper at IEEE. Even the outcome is not the same. you make a near-to fullscreen label, while I respected the OPs label width dimension and origin.

Comment: Where is the leak? You may hold even 100 strong references, all of those will be released when the view will be dealloced (in case of the code I've shown). That's some kind of a joke, there is no leak over here. Go to IEEE and teach them your way thinking about leaks. I've already told both my intentions and why there is neither leak nor retain cycle, so I won't continue this completely mad discussion unless someone tells why there could be a leak in it - if so i'd gladly learn. Atm I don't see a leak. Especially your code is missing some points also. EOT for me.